# Moving chosen records generated from MYSQL to another table - checkbox and button

Tags: php, html, mysql

HTML Table:

```
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><h3>ID</h3></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th><h3>ID</h3></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php getClicksReport(); ?>
        </tbody>
```

function PHP:

```
function getClicksReport() {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clicks ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($click = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $click['id'] . '<span class="idcheckbox"><input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$click['id'].'"/></td>';
}
```

}

and.....

```
if(isset($_POST['akceptlead']) && $_POST['id']){
$total = count($_POST['id']);
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
        $akceptujLeada = mysql_query("DELETE FROM leads WHERE id ='".$_POST['id'][$i]."'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    header("Location: clicksReport.php");
```

}

I Select record in table html, click on the button "accept chosen", but nothing happens.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You should post your code here instead of paste.ofcode.org . This is to avoid broken links in the future. Your code doesn't seem too big to fit, but a good way of avoiding that is to remove anything that does not matter to the question.

Comment: @Nicola Pedretti - Ok. I Paste all code here.